# Extract Information from post content (using regex?)

Tags: plugin-development, content, regex, customization

I'm trying to replace some custom strings in my content before saving the post.
I have got the $data["post_content"] which includes strings like %replaceContent:{type}% . Now I need to extract that string, read the {type} and replace the string afterwards depending on what's inside of {type}. I imagine this would best be done using regex, unfortunately I don't really know how to go about this. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs to stackoverflow. Here's a solution anyway:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\%replaceContent:{(.*?)}\%/', 'do_replacements', $content);

function do_replacements($matches){

  $type = $matches[1]; // here's your {type}
  $replacement = "...replacement for {$type}";  

  return $replacement; 
}
```